# @emotin/react: Class names do not match when Composition is used within forwardRef

Tags: next.js, emotion

This code is working but class names is not mathing.　@emotion/react is using 11.10.4.
If Composition ([]) is not used, the error is resolved. Using a component wrapped in forwardRef and using Composition will result in a class name mismatch.　We are looking for solutions.

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <div
      css={[
        css`
          display: flex;
        `,
      ]}
    >
      <RefComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

const RefComponent = forwardRef<any, any>((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <h1
      ref={ref}
      css={[
        css`
          color: red;
        `,
      ]}
    >
      Hello
    </h1>
  );
});
```